# Cannot svn checkout on vboxsf mount (windows host - ubuntu guest)

Tags: virtualbox, network-share

I have my `C:\Users\Mike\Projects` directory registered for sharing in VirtualBox as "projects" (full access, permanent).

In my Ubuntu 10.04 server VM, I am using the following mount command:

`sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,exec projects /home/mike/projects`

The shared directory is mounted.

```
mike@zsce:~$ ll
drwxrwxrwx 1 mike mike 4.0K 2011-02-01 10:32 projects
```

If I create a file from Windows I can see and delete it on Ubuntu and vice-versa.  So far, so good.

The problem is that I cannot do svn checkouts from the guest here.

```
mike@zsce:~/projects$ svn co svn://server/myproject/ ./myproject
svn: Can't move 'myproject/.svn/tmp/entries' to 'myproject/.svn/entries': Operation not permitted
```

My intention is to use the VM as a local development server.  Use Windows 7 for all IDE/e-mail/web/etc needs and just use the server to test and commit my code.  The Windows IDE and the VM's web server would be operating on the same source code.

However, the entries file ends up not being writable by me.

```
mike@zsce:~/projects/myproject/.svn$ ll entries
-r-xr-xr-x 1 mike mike 166 2011-02-01 10:34 entries
```

Even `root` cannot delete the files without first executing `chmod -R 777`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution.  Extensive Google search revealed other people had the same problem and were not able to find solutions either.

I ended up not using the Shared Folders feature of VirtualBox with vboxsf and instead just created a Windows share and mounted it under the Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 3):

upgrade to svn 1.7 and it will work.  see [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22048&start=15) .

although it is a bug in vbox, but seems subversion team is actively fixing it...

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution was [posted here by lipi](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22048&start=15). But is is a hack-a-round.

> For those desperately looking for a workaround, below is a hack I just added to `svn_io_remove_file` and `svn_io_file_rename` in subversion-1.6.12. It works for me but still needs `dmode=755` in the mount options.